# How to activate Modal from a select box in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

'Add project' has to fire a Bootstrap 3 modal. How to do that?

```
<option>Project A</option>
<option>Project B</option>
<option>Project C</option>
<option>Add Project </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call bootstrap's modal on select's change event.

```
$('select').change(function () {
  var addProj = $('select option:selected').val();
  if(addProj === 'Add Project'){
    $('#example').modal();
  }
});
```

DEMO http://jsbin.com/qetarabu/1/edit